# Kivy BoxLayout align widgets to the top border

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using the following Kivy code to create BoxLayout with buttons:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    width: 200
    size_hint_x: None

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        text: 'btn1'

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        text: 'btn2'

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        text: 'btn3'
```

But buttons stick to the bottom edge, how can i push them towards the top edge of the layout?

[image]

Comment: try: `BoxLayout:     size: root.size`

Comment: @bigOTHER I don't want to scale this layout to the size of parent widget and it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can also put an empty Widget at the end to take up the space.

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    width: 200
    size_hint_x: None

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        text: 'btn1'

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        text: 'btn2'

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        text: 'btn3'

    Widget:
```

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use a [StackLayout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.stacklayout.html) for this, to make sure the buttons go from top to bottom.

You could also try using padding with the BoxLayout

From the kivy BoxLayout docs:

> Padding between layout box and children: [padding_left, padding_top,
>   padding_right, padding_bottom].
>
> padding also accepts a two argument form [padding_horizontal,
>   padding_vertical] and a one argument form [padding].
>
> Changed in version 1.7.0: Replaced NumericProperty with
>   VariableListProperty.
>
> padding is a VariableListProperty and defaults to [0, 0, 0, 0].

For instance, yours might look like:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    width: 200
    size_hint_x: None
    padding: 0, 0, 0, bottom_padding_here
```

What you set it to, so that it always puts the buttons in the right place, no matter the screen size, is another matter. But totally doable I believe.

If you were to add or remove buttons at some later point, you would adjust the padding etc.

Comment: I've tried padding, but you need to specify exact value, otherwise buttons will be pushed too far. So it is inconvenient to calculate it every time.

Comment: But StackLayout seems to be fine, I think you should put it on top in your answer.

Comment: I agree that StackLayout should be the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridLayout` with `cols: 1` instead of `BoxLayout`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).